# Grep + sed combination

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Im making a skrip to change and delete some string from sql, now i need change the word "InnoDB DEFAULT" for a ")" ¿Any help?

Script:

```
#! /bin/bash
ub1=foo1.sql;
ub2='';

pelar1=`grep -v "LOCK TABLES" $ub1 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p5`
pelar2=`grep -v "[--]" p5 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p4`
pelar3=`grep -v "[/*!]" p4 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p3`
pelar4=`grep -v "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" p3 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p2`
pelar5=`grep -v "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT" p2 | sed -e "/^$/s/" > limpio`
```

> the problem is on pelar5

```
eliminacion=`rm p5 p4 p3 p2`

var1=''
var2=''
count=0

#primero vamos a pelar el archivo para que muestre lo menos posible
```

> rough translation: "first we will peel the file to show as little as possible"

```
$pelar1
$pelar2
$pelar3
$pelar4
```

foo.sql who i give at start

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabla`;
CREATE TABLE `tabla` (
  `colmn1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colmn2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tabla` VALUES ('13','20');
```

Desired code :

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabla`;
    CREATE TABLE `tabla` (
      `colmn1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `colmn2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
    );

INSERT INTO `tabla` VALUES ('13','20');
```

that its the output:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabla`;
CREATE TABLE `tabla` (
  `colmn1` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `colmn2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
INSERT INTO `tabla` VALUES ('13','20');
```

Comment: How about showing sample input and expected output ?

Comment: Can you explain what you meant to accomplish with those `grep -v` lines that redundantly remove the blank lines from their output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All those statements that assign pelar[1-5] are redirecting output, so nothing is likely being put in the variables, which are then executed as empty strings. Why?

```
pelar1=`grep -v "LOCK TABLES" $ub1 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p5`
```

This selects for output all lines of `$ub1` that do not have the string `"LOCK TABLES"`, and sends them through a sed which deletes any that are blank. I assume all LOCK TABLE statements are on single lines, so now P5 has neither LOCK TABLE statements or blank lines.

The output from this command is all redirected to p5, so there is nothing assigned to `$pelar1`. (I'm also curious if p5 means "peel 5" as a countdown, while "pelar1" is counting up. Be consistent.)

```
pelar2=`grep -v "[--]" p5 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p4`
```

This statement seems intended to eliminate comment lines, including any line with explanatory comments after a valid statement. I assume you know that there must have been none of those you wanted to keep. It also `sed`-strips blank lines again, but there would be none in P5 since you already did that. Again, it redirects output to P4, so nothing will be assigned in `$pelar2`.

However, as I read it, you are passing `grep` a character class. This will indeed remove comments, but also *ANY* line with *any* dash in it at all. Probably not what was intended.

```
pelar3=`grep -v "[/*!]" p4 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p3`
```

This is probably meant to strip lines with the start of a comment. It assumes the comment will not span across lines, and that there will be no short comments using this syntax on a line with code you meant to keep, which is fine if you know that will never happen. It again deletes non-existant blank lines, and returns nothing to `$pelar3`.

However, it again uses a character class, so will remove any line with any forward slash, asterisk, or exclamation point.

```
pelar4=`grep -v "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" p3 | sed -e '/^$/d' > p2`
```

This eliminates `DROP TABLE` statements; again, removes nonexistant blank lines, returns nothing to the var.

```
pelar5=`grep -v "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT" p2 | sed -e "/^$/s/" > limpio`
```

This removes the InnoDB lines, with a pipe to an incomplete `sed` substitution.
My test -

```
> sed -e "/^$/s/"<x
> sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command
```

Were you not getting an error?

To sum - keeping the assumptions such as that commands do not span lines and that it is safe to remove lines with comment starts, a rewrite:

```
egrep -v '^$|/*!|--|LOCK TABLES|DROP TABLE IF EXISTS' foo1.sql |
    sed 's/) *ENGINE=InnoDB *DEFAULT *CHARSET=latin1 *;/);/' >foo2.sql
```

This ought to do the same general thing without creating intermediary temp files.

Apologies if this sounds in any way negative. I hope it helps.

Be sure those assumptions are what you intended.

> [UPDATE]

If I start with -

```
-- single line comment
/*! preprocessor stuff */
LOCK TABLES and CHAIRS
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabla`;

CREATE TABLE `tabla` (
  'colmn1' varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  'colmn2' varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tabla` VALUES ('13','20');
```

it produces for me

```
CREATE TABLE `tabla` (
  'colmn1' varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  'colmn2' varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `tabla` VALUES ('13','20');
```

Is that not what you asked for?
(In pelar4 you explicitly `grep -v "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" p3`...)

Comment: Is there no other method combined ?, think that these lines, the language can vary

Comment: Ah. give me some exmples, maybe elaborate your OP. We'll see what we can come up with.

Comment: Im parching the scrip, its for transform a .sql to a simple sample of txt

Comment: Does the above not do what you needed?

Comment: i got the problem now with the last sed " sed 's/) *ENGINE=InnoDB *DEFAULT *CHARSET=latin1 *;/);/' >foo2.sql" it delate all

Comment: I don't understand. You were originally `grep -v`-ing the whole line away, and your example explicitly shows what you wanted was `);`. Please clarify.